# Email CSV using MFMailComposeViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using this code to export CSV file https://gist.github.com/kenechilearnscode/2d5d35f550f593332319

And it is exporting correctly but I want to email this CSV using MFMailComposeViewController. The above code opens an applicationActivities from where I can choose mail and the file is attached but the subject and recipients are not set. Code I am using to email the CSV is following. Its setting the subject and recipients etc but not attaching the CSV file.

```
if( MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() ) {
    print("Can send email.")

    let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self

    //Set the subject and message of the email
    mailComposer.setSubject("Patient Data")
    mailComposer.setMessageBody("Please find attached herewith complete patient data", isHTML: false)
    mailComposer.setToRecipients(secondaryEmailList)
    mailComposer.setCcRecipients([masterEmail])
    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "export", ofType: "csv") {
        print("File path loaded.")

        if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
            print("File data loaded.")
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "export")
        }
    }
    self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is the code I am using to generate CSV file

```
func saveAndExport(exportString: String) {
    let exportFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "export.csv"
    let exportFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)
    FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: exportFilePath, contents: NSData() as Data, attributes: nil)
    var fileHandleError: NSError? = nil
    var fileHandle: FileHandle? = nil
    do {
        fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: exportFileURL as URL)
    } catch {
        print("Error with fileHandle")
    }

    if fileHandle != nil {
        fileHandle!.seekToEndOfFile()
        let csvData = exportString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        fileHandle!.write(csvData!)

        fileHandle!.closeFile()

        let firstActivityItem = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)
        let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
            UIActivityType.assignToContact,
            UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
            UIActivityType.postToFlickr,
            UIActivityType.postToVimeo,
            UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo
        ]

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you looking for the CSV file in the app's resource bundle? There's no way you could have saved the generated CSV file in the app's resource bundle. Load the file from where ever you actually save it when it is generated.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  One sentence says "I can choose mail and the file is attached but the subject and recipients are not set" and the next sentence says " Its setting the subject and recipients etc but not attaching the CSV file".  Which is it?  is csv being attached or not?  are the recipients being attached?

Comment: What I mean is that when I use the exact code here: https://gist.github.com/kenechilearnscode/2d5d35f550f593332319
It asks to email or share when I email it attaches the file. But if I use MFMailComposeViewController to email it doesn't attach the file

Comment: @rmaddy I have generated the CSV using the the code here: https://gist.github.com/kenechilearnscode/2d5d35f550f593332319 So can you please tell where should I make changes in my code

Comment: Don't post a link to other code. [Edit] your question to include relevant code. Mainly, show the code for writing your CSV data to a file. Be sure to include how the full path is calculated. But in short, your code to send the email has to load the CSV from the same path it was written to.

Comment: @rmaddy edited with the code I am using

Comment: As I said, you need to load the CSV file from the same path used to write it.